# Rails 4, Capybara: form_tag produces nil params hash. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

Rails 4: While running a feature spec with Capybara, my params hash is nil.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
# app/views/comics/index.html.erb

<%= form_tag subscriptions_subscribe_path do %>
  <%= label_tag :email %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email]%>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit'%>
<% end %>


# spec/features/subscribe_feature_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'
require 'pry'

feature 'subscribe to email list' do
  scenario 'success' do
    visitor_email = 'Monkey@Biz.com'
    visit '/'
    fill_in :email, with: visitor_email
    click_on 'Submit'
    # ...balance omitted...
  end 
end

# app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb

class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  def subscribe
    binding.pry
    # params = nil ... WHY?       
    # params[:email] => undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
    # ...balance omitted...
  end
end
```

I've got a bonehead error somewhere in the code above.

My view contains only a single instance of the word "Submit", so Capybara is not clicking the wrong link.

logs

```
$ tail -f log/test.log
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-19 15:01:07 -0700
Processing by ComicsController#index as HTML
  Comic Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comics".* FROM "comics"
  Rendered comics/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_navlinks.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_navlinks.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 349ms (Views: 348.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
Started POST "/subscriptions/subscribe" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-19 15:01:08 -0700
Processing by SubscriptionsController#subscribe as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "email"=>"Monkey@Biz.com", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Comment: Does your test log show any params being submitted?

Comment: searching app/log/test.log does not reveal 'Monkey@Biz.com', if I'm looking in the right place.

Comment: Scratch that. Adding logs above. The logs show I'm passing params.

Comment: So rails is receiving the parameters, so it's not a capybara issue - In your code, you don't happen to have do something like `params = ...`  which would create a local variable named params, that would shield the method named params that would normally return the hash?  Other than that look at any before actions you have, and make sure they're not screwing with the hash

Comment: I'm thinking this is a white-label strong params thing...experimenting now

Comment: Okay...I white-labeled the params I need (:email) and called the internal to make it work...finally I need to access the params via @_params... I stumbled on this, and it works, but I'm baffled...

Comment: It sounds like you're shadowing the params method somehow